# Associating records with Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have this setup:

```
App.MyModel = Em.Model.extend({
  someValue: DS.attr('string'),
  parent   : DS.belongsTo('mymodel',{async:true, inverse:'rooms'}),
  rooms    : DS.hasMany('mymodel', {async:true, inverse:'parent'})
});

App.MyRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model:function(params){
    var parent = this.store.find('mymodel', params.parent_id);
    return this.store.createRecord('mymodel',{parent:parent});
  }
});
```

`params.parent_id` has the ID I want, so `find()` should return the right record.

Then `someValue` gets bound in a input box of a template and after input the action `create` gets called.

```
App.MyController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions:{
    create:function(){
      this.get('model').save();
    }
  }
});
```

But when the data is send to the server, only `someValue` has the right data, `parent` is `null`.

I don't know if the error is in the model-definition or in the way I set the relationship.

**How do I set relations on records correctly?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The promises of the `find` should resolve to the actual object.

But this didn't work when using it like in the question.

There is a different method, that can be used when the needed record has already been loaded.

```
model: function(params){
  return this.store.createRecord('mymodel', {
    'parent': this.store.getById('mymodel', params.parent_id)
  });  
}
```

This works, because route I came from already loaded the parent.